# Excel shows count even though a column is blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

After using a simple excel formula(Consider **Len(I1)**) i get values in next column "J" either invalid or blank (if the length is valid). Now the problem i am facing is if all the values are valid (which gives all blanks in column J except header of column J) the count of column J will be equal to Count of column I(As shown in pic 204). I mean if all the values are valid in column I which leads to all blanks in column J should give the count as 1 (only its header) but its not happening. what do you suggest me to do.

[image]

Comment: Excel will count cells which are "formula blanks" as cells containing data if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: @ Shrivallabha Redij Exactly

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Kindly take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JonSmith The way Excel is showing cannot be altered, I'm afraid. Do you intend to use the result somewhere i.e. by means of formula etc or is it of only academic interest?

Comment: Well i want to use the results.

Comment: try using countif() and counting exactly what you expect, but not the blanks...

Comment: Try **COUNTA(range)-COUNTBLANK(range)**. Or filter to select the blanks and `ClearContents`

Comment: Although the COUNT in the bottom bar will show blanks in the count, the COUNT() function does not.  You could simply use COUNT(range).  This is more than semantic in nature, because if you were using an entire column as a range, tegancp's suggestion would yield an incorrect result.